# Why does randint not work in a matrix but everywhere else? (Noob Python)

Tags: python, matrix

I've been making a seating chart in Python that displays absences in the place of each seat. To make a list of example absences I decided to use randint to generate a random value between 0-15 but when I try it in the matrix it doesn't work. However the same line used outside the matrix and just printed worked fine.. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import random

student0Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student1Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student2Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student3Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student4Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student5Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student6Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student7Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student8Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)
student9Abs_EX = random.randint(0,15)

print("\n\nExample Absences: \n")
matrix = [[student0Abs_EX + '\t\t', student1Abs_EX + '\t\t', student2Abs_EX + '\t\t'], [student3Abs_EX + '\t\t', student4Abs_EX + '\t\t', student5Abs_EX + '\t\t'], [student6Abs_EX + '\t\t', 'Empty' + '\t\t', student7Abs_EX + '\t\t'], ['Empty' + '\t\t', student8Abs_EX+ '\t\t', student9Abs_EX + '\t\t']]
for row in matrix:
    print ' '.join(row)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [There's no need to put "solved" in your title.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/175248)  If an answer helped you, accept it; if you figured it out on your own, post it as an answer and accept it instead.  An accepted answer is somewhat tantamount to "solved".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the `random.randint` function.  The problem is that you are trying to add an `int` and a `str` together whenever you do one of these:  `student0Abs_EX + '\t\t'`.

One fix is to change all those to `str(student0Abs_EX) + '\t\t'`

The `str` function converts the int to a corresponding string.

Comment: Ahhhh.. Thank you, haha.. I actually tried this first but I only tried it on one and still got the error.. I replaced all with str() tags and it worked, I feel stupid but thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

because you can't just concatenate an `int` and a `str`.

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1 +'2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

it seems you just need an text representation of a random matrix. try other ways to create in instead of `[student0Abs_EX + '\t\t', student1Abs_EX + '\t\t', student2Abs_EX + '\t\t'], ...`